# KTable suppress(Suppressed.untilTimeLimit()) not contains records the specified time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have implemented a stream processing app that makes some calculations and transformations, and send the result to an output topic.
After that, I read from that topic and I want to suppress the results for 35", just like a timer, meaning that all the output records from that suppress will be sended to an specific "timeout" topic.

The simplified code looks like this:

```
inputStream
     .suppress(Suppressed.untilTimeLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(35), Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
     .toStream()
     .peek((key, value) -> LOGGER.warn("incidence with Key: {} timeout -> Time = {}", key, 35))
     .filterNot((key, value) -> value.isDisconnection())
```

The problem I have here is that suppress contains the records during an arbitrary time, not the specified 35 seconds.
For more information I'm using event-time extracted in the former process described at the beginning, and records are arriving each second;

Thanks

**Update**

This is an input record example:

```
rowtime: 4/8/20 8:26:33 AM UTC, key: 34527882, value: {"incidenceId":"34527882","installationId":"18434","disconnection":false,"timeout":false, "creationDate":"1270801593"}
```

Comment: So your problem is because timestamp of input stream changed (dued to a TimestampExtractor in upstream processor) cause suppress does not work as expected?

Comment: Not really, I need the event time because I want to suppress records based in the event timestamp. The code showed in the questions gets input records with the correct timestamp to use. Having that time in mind, the I want the suppress to contain results for a key during 35 seconds

Comment: Yes, I mean this `event timestamp` is extracted from record payload, right? can you give an example with an input and expected output, with timestamp info

Comment: I edited the post with an example input, the output should be the same record, unless `disconnection == true`. In that case the record is ignored

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue some time ago, and the reason why suppress contains the records during an arbitrary time it's due to the fact that the suppress operator uses what they call `stream time` instead of the intuitive `wall-clock time`.

> As of now, `untilTimeLimit` only supports `stream time`, which limits its usefulness. Work is underway to add a `wall-clock time` option, expanding this feature into a general rate control mechanism.
>
> The important aspects of time for Suppress are:
>
> - The timestamp of each record: This is also known as event time.
> - What time is “now”? Stream processing systems have two main choices here:
>
>   1. The intuitive “now” is wall-clock time, the time you would see if you look at a clock on the wall while your program is running.
>   2. There is also stream time, which is essentially the maximum timestamp your program has observed in the stream so far. If you’ve been polling a topic, and you’ve seen records with timestamps 10, 11, 12, 11, then the current stream time is 12.

Reference: [Kafka Streams’ Take on Watermarks and Triggers](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers/)